# Mapbox not displaying with custom tileset in Jupyter

Tags: pandas, jupyter, mapbox, visualization

Using mapboxgl (latest version) and Jupyter, I can display an overlay on a vanilla style, but a custom style with tileset does not render. The purpose is to show which university printers students use the most and the custom style separates dorms from non-dorms.

Given a df with the following data:

```
,printer_name,lat,lon,total_pages
0,cedarprint_3m_lng,39.752334,-83.812330,199607
1,cedarprint_3vp_lng,39.753248,-83.812825,201207
2,cedarprint_app_lng,39.748560,-83.810260,239829
3,cedarprint_bdp_lng,39.752325,-83.816009,42962
4,cedarprint_bts_111,39.748896,-83.810867,124588
```

I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from mapboxgl.viz import *
from mapboxgl.utils import *

color_breaks = [round(cp_sum_df['total_pages'].quantile(q=x*0.1), 2) for x in range(2, 10)]
color_stops = create_color_stops(color_breaks, colors='Blues')
points = df_to_geojson(df, properties=['total_pages', 'printer_name'], lat='lat', lon='lon', precision=8)

style='mapbox://styles/coopermj/ckzfnbawg000414o82e5pio5j'

viz2 = CircleViz(points,
                  access_token=token,
                  color_property='total_pages',
                  color_stops=color_stops,
                  center=(-83.8130, 39.74890),
                  zoom=16,
                  style=style
                 )
viz2.show()
```

and it fails to render and I have javascript errors in the console.

But, if I use a public style (or even a custom one without a tileset), it displays fine.

The style is marked public in mapbox. Is there something about the rasterized tileset that changes the approach? Thanks!

Comment: What are the JavaScript errors?

Comment: Hmmm...`token` is undefined. It seems to me like the token is associated with the account... could you perhaps share the token, and then revoke it and generate a new one (if that's even possible) when the question is answered?